# Prove a group is solvable iff it is a subgroup of the group of upper-triangular invertible matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

i've stumbled upon this interesting claim stated in the title. Anyone got an idea how to show this is right? Seems like proving a subgroup of upper triangular invertible matrices is a solvable group shouldnt be too hard, but the other direction - not sure about it at all.

The interesting part about it is that my definition of a solvable group is unintuitive and even a bit messy but this one is far nicer.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a consequence of the Lie-Kolchin theorem

Comment: I don't think it can be true in general. The commutator subgroup of a group of upper triangular matrices consists of unitriangular matrices and is nilpotent. The solvable group $S_4$, for example, has commutator subgroup $A_4$, which is not nilpotent, so $S_4$ cannot be isomorphic to a group of upper triangular matrices.

Comment: As Derek says, this is false. There is a true claim along these lines about solvable *algebraic* groups, but it requires some additional hypotheses and I'm not sure exactly what those are. See Chapter 17 of Milne (http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/iAG200.pdf) for a discussion.